# Connection to Azure from VS 2013 failed. (secure channel for SSL/TLS)

Tags: visual-studio, azure

According to the walk-through posted on

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/

connecting to Azure from within Visual Studio 2013 should be trivial.
However I get the following error:

*'An error occured during the sign in process: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'management.core.windows.net.'*

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Check your system time...

Comment: Sorry but I am not following. Check my sistem time for what exactly?

Comment: If it's off by a couple of days, the SSL handshake will fail.

Comment: My system time is fine. I've read that Azure uses UTC Time Zone and have tried changing my system to UTC without luck. Anything else I should try?